# Create smallest unique number from two byte

Tags: algorithm

As we all know a byte range is 0 to 255 
i have two byte, I want to create another number that is reversible but with minimum length that combine these two number and create a new one, the simplest solution is

a = b1 * 1000 + b2

reverse would be

b1 = a / 1000
b2 = a % 1000

the length of above solution varying 0 to 6 length, i want a formula with FIXED and minimum length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encode:

```
x = b1 * 256 + b2;
x = x + 10000;
```

Decode:

```
x = x - 10000;
b1 = x >> 8;
b2 = x & 255;
```

Encoded result always has length 5 (`10000` through `75535` inclusive). And since there are 65536 different pairs (b1, b2) you can't encode them into numbers of length < 5 (because there are at most 10000 such numbers).

Comment: D'Oh. My solution but with one less digit. I don't know _how_ that could have escaped me. +1.

Comment: Your solution is great, Is there any smaller one ? for example 4 digit with some kind of complex formula ?

Comment: @Ehsan: How could there be 4 digits when there are 65536 different input values?

Comment: Why are you adding 1000? Why not just prefix shorter numbers with '0'?

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest general purpose solution here would be

```
a = b1 * 256 + b2;
```

aka

```
a = (b1 << 8) | b2;
```

Then to get them back (assuming you've got unsigned bytes available):

```
b1 = (a >> 8) & 0xff;
b2 = a & 0xff;
```

That will produce a 2-byte value for all inputs, unless you deem the results of `b1=0, b2=*` to be one byte (as every value is less than 256). You could *potentially* interleave things, such that the low four bits of each input byte ends up in the low eight bits of the output, so that you'd end up with a value of less than 256 for (`b1 < 16, b2 < 16`). Frankly it's easiest to always just consider it as a 2-byte value, using the above shifting.

Using 2 bytes is clearly a minimum, and it's easily achievable.

If that's not what you're looking for, please give more information.

EDIT: I've been assuming you're looking for a fixed *binary* length. If you want a fixed *decimal* length, use falagar's solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a fixed-length number when expressed in decimal, you can use:

```
a = 100,000 + b1 * 256 + b2
```

That will give you a number from 100,000 to 165,535 inclusive.

To reverse the operation:

```
b1 = (a - 100,000) / 256
b2 = (a - 100,000) % 256
```

Comment: falagar's solution gives a smaller fixed size.

Comment: Yes, I must be getting senile :-)